# Set multiple combo boxes to same datasource

Tags: c#, combobox

I have several comboboxes on my form in panel1. I'm using this code to add same datasources to panel1 comboBoxes;

```
foreach (Control x in this.Panel1.Controls)
{
    if (x is ComboBox)
    {
        ((ComboBox)x).DataSource = new BindingSource(tblbatteryBindingSource, null);
        ((ComboBox)x).DisplayMember = "description";
    }
}
```

Using new binding source is because of using same datasource.

But there is a problem here: in my datasource table I have columns like this: Id - Name - Count

When I am adding two rows with the same namem in combo box it returns only first one counts and it ignore others.

A sample for more understanding:

```
Id     Name     Count
1      first    10
2      second   10
3      third    10
4      first    12
5      first    5
```

This is my table ^

but now in combo box when I choosing a value counts are showing up in a label:

```
Id-> 1       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 2       cmb1.SelectedItem = "second"     label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 3       cmb1.SelectedItem = "third"      label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 4       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 5       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "10"
```

this is what happend to me. but it is not true. it should be like this:

```
Id-> 1       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 2       cmb1.SelectedItem = "second"     label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 3       cmb1.SelectedItem = "third"      label1.Text = "10"
Id-> 4       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "12"
Id-> 5       cmb1.SelectedItem = "first"      label1.Text = "5"
```

Sorry for my bad English and bad explaination.

Please tell me what to do? I have searched everywhere already!

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide correct column names to the DisplayMember and ValueMember of the ComboBox. As per your example table check the following:

```
(ComboBox)x).DisplayMember = "Name";
(ComboBox)x).ValueMember = "Count";
```

I have tested following code to verify your results:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           

        label1.Text = label2.Text = label3.Text = String.Empty;

        // strCon is connection string
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from testTable", con);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;

        con.Open();
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        foreach (Control x in this.Panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (x is ComboBox)
            {
                ((ComboBox)x).DataSource = new BindingSource(dt, null);
                ((ComboBox)x).DisplayMember = "Name";
                ((ComboBox)x).ValueMember = "Count";
            }
        }
    }

    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

    private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label2.Text = comboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }

    private void comboBox3_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label3.Text = comboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString();
    }
```

I hope it helps :)